# How to change 3D - TextMesh Pro inside string with script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have keyboad prefab and 6 keys prefab. I put keys with **Instantiate**. Every keys have got TextMeshPro objects. I need to change these characters with script. But when I try to get TextMeshPro component, console returns null.

```
Debug.Log(GetComponent<TextMeshPro>());
```

[image]

My code part is here;

```
private void SetUp()
{
    // Global Screen Height
    var worldScreenHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2.0;
    // Global Screen Width
    var worldScreenWidth = worldScreenHeight / Screen.height * Screen.width;
    // Keyboard
    var keyboardSize = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.size.x;
    var neededScale = worldScreenWidth / keyboardSize;
    var neededYPosition = (worldScreenHeight / 2) - (keyboardSize / 2);
    transform.localScale = new Vector3((float)neededScale, (float)neededScale, 0);
    transform.position = new Vector3(0, -(float)neededYPosition, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < Characters.Length; i++)
    {
        double angle = ((i / (Characters.Length / (double)2)) * Math.PI);
        GameObject newObject = Instantiate(Keys, new Vector2((float)(keyboardSize / 2 * 0.6 * neededScale * Math.Cos(angle)), (float)(keyboardSize / 2 * 0.6 * neededScale * Math.Sin(angle) - neededYPosition)), Quaternion.identity, transform) as GameObject;
        newObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
        // I can't access textmeshpro
        Debug.Log(GetComponent<TextMeshPro>());
    }

}
```

How can change strings in TextMeshPro?

Comment: I'm looking for same answer

Comment: This script is placed in KeyText gameObject or in TMP object (child of KeyText)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `GetComponent<TextMeshPro>()` to `GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>()`.

There are two TextMeshPro components who both derive from TMP_Text.

The first component of type **TextMeshPro** is designed to replace the old TextMesh which uses the MeshRenderer.

The 2nd of type **TextMeshProUGUI** is designed to replace UI.Text and designed to work with the CanvasRenderer and Canvas system, which seems the one you're using.

Comment: I'm not using canvas TextMesh. I'm using 3d TextMeshPro.